# Not-null assertion operator (!!) weird behavior

Tags: kotlin, compiler-errors, nullpointerexception

I'm using the current latest Kotlin version (`1.9.22`) and ran into a behavior that I can't explain.

This code produces a *runtime* error (`NullPointerException`):

```kotlin
fun main() {
    var name: String? = null
    println(name!!.length)
}
```

While this code produces a *compile* error (`Unresolved reference: length`)

```kotlin
fun main() {
    var name: String? = "Joe"
    name = null
    println(name!!.length)
}
```

How come that simply doing a reassignment of the nullable `name` variable saves me from the `NullPointerException`? I'd expect the two code snippets to be functionally identical.

Answer (score 6):

In the second snippet, `name = null` *smart casts* it to `Nothing?`, that's why `.length` can't be resolved

Comment: I'm fairly early in my Kotlin studies and I can't decipher the _why_ from your answer, so I haven't marked it as "accepted" (yet). Is it a Kotlin safety mechanism? Are you sure the cast happens at `name = null`? Because if I remove the line that comes after then `name` is still a `String?` (according to IntelliJ). And why do I get a `NullPointerException` if I exchange `name!!.length` with e.g. `name!!::class` or `name!!.hashCode()`? How can I see that it becomes a `Nothing?`? With these follow up question I now realize that I should have been more thoroughly in my original question.

Comment: @joakie "Are you sure the cast happens at `name = null`" – hmm, checked it again, and it looks like I made a mistake and the actual smart cast happens at `name!!`, where it's cast to `Nothing` because it was set to `null`. My bad, sorry

Comment: @joakie but yes, I see that the logic from the previous comment is not relevant for the first case from the question. Turned out to be harder than I thought

Comment: @joakie moreover, the second case doesn't work this way if `name` is not a local variable (as, in this case, compiler thinks that the value may be changed somewhere else in a different thread). But if the variable is local, as in the example, it can only be `null` before `name!!`, so it goes `Nothing` instead of `String`

Comment: @joakie as for case 1, I currently believe it's due to a compiler imperfection, but maybe I'm wrong

Comment: thanks for your inputs! Perhaps one needs to dig into the compiler source code to find the true reason, or maybe this Kotlin behavior will feel obvious after some time when I have progressed in my studies. I'll leave the question as "open" for now to inspire further input. I guess the better place to ask is at https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/, but that feels overkill, I don't have a spaceship that will blow up because of the behavior inconsistency (my words) in the snippets above =)